# problem with configuration VPS and nodejs application

Tags: node.js, ssl, server, configuration, vps

[this is the website link its show bad request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic3yx.png)  
after deployed successful and point the domain successful
still the website desnt work
I think theres a problem with conf file
etc/nginx/sites-available dose not contain defult.conf file
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled contain these files :

default.conf  twtsys.com.conf  twtsys.com.conf.save
twtsys.com this is my project name
witch file should I edit ? and what to write in it exactly please

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name twtsys.com MY IP;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  # Adjust port if necessary
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

this is the default.conf file